# SXA multisite question

Tags: sxa, multisite

We are using Sitecore 9.0 and are currently investigating SXA multisites posibilities.

Our dream scenario would be like this :

- One tenant
- severals sites, siteA, siteB etc.
- each site uses same host header, f.ex. mysite.com
- each site has different virtual folder , sitea, siteb etc.
- sites would live in this urls : https://mysite.com/sitea, https://mysite.com/siteb etc.

Is this scenario possible with SXA?

The idea is that IIS configuration (site + host header) would be done once, and adding extra sites would only be done in Sitecore.

Right now we can not get this to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, it is possible.

ISS binding -> `mysite.com`

Example site configuration
[image]

I think you might have problems with sites order.
**Open Sxa Site Manager**
[image]

And make sure that you order them correctly (if there is any site on the top that has `*` binding, none of the sites below will be considered during site resolution)

So basically eliminate conflicts

**Example conflict**

To solve this, site **int** should be first as it a has a virtual folder but **SiteA** not
[image]

Comment: Hi
This was exactly what I needed.